# ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist LINE 2: ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,4326)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

```
ALTER TABLE public."MyData"
    ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,4326)
```

I get following error, while executing above query,

> ERROR: type “geometry” does not exist LINE 2: ADD COLUMN geom
>   geometry(POINT,4326)

please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

you must install PostGIS first, enable it in the current DB and make sure that the user can access it.

```
--is it installed?
select postgis_version();

-- enable postgis
create extension postgis();

-- ensure the schema containing PostGIS is in the user search path:
show search_path;
```

Comment: Yes sir I am already install but i Solve this problem because I forgot Extension include the postGis